# Android textview is missing the line underneath

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, input, textview

I recently updated to Android Studio 2.2.2. 
I am looking to add a textview to one of my apps. But, when I drag and drop an edittext into the layout, the line underneath, or anything denoting that its a separate input; the only formatting makes it appear just as the background. That is, the input has no formatting.

I would like it to have some sort of formatting; either a border, a single line underneath, so that the user can see where to click and enter their information.

What properties do I need to do this, and where can they be manipulated?

This is the XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/location_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:divider="@android:string/ok">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MemeMe"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like

[image]
Normally I'd drag and drop from the widget bar on the left side of android studio, but it doesn't seem like Android Studio did such a thing in this case, and its probably not wise to rely on the IDE to do such things like that without me knowing how it does the things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/location_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/location"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: android studio can't find that class

Comment: Are you using N sdk for rendering the layout?, if so, change it to sdk 23 or lower.

Comment: it looks like I'm at android 6.0 marshmallow API 23

Comment: Take a screenshot of that bug. I think your Android Studio is misconfigured.

Comment: Make sure you are including compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0' and compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' in your build.gradle file

Comment: Did you already check out these lines compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0' and compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' in your build.gradle file?

Comment: that's really odd. So I ran the app and the line I was looking for was there; but in the preview it wasn't. Any idea why? Regardless, Thanks for the help Jose Ricardo!

Comment: that sometimes happens. Some elements aren't shown on the layout design preview but on the app running.